# Get records from DB searching a period between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar, datepicker

i'm trying to get records from a mysql that are included into a certain period between two dates (these two dates are respectively date_start, date_end and are stored in two different columns).

what i'm doing now in my select query is:

```
   .. WHERE MONTH(date_start) >= '".$month_start."' and DAY(date_start) >= '".$day_start."'" AND MONTH(date_end) <= '".$month_end."' and DAY(date_end) <= '".$day_end."'"
```

that query works but only in some cases, not at all!

Any suggestion please?

table sample here:

id_period;date_start;date_end;
27;0000-04-02;0000-05-31;

|| *id_period* || *date_start* || *date_end* ||
|| 41          || 0000-11-01   || 0000-11-30 ||

Comment: What is the output of month_start, day_start etc? Are you able to output a printed query? This will help someone provide an answer because there could be a number of reasons.

Comment: month_start = 09
day_start = 01
month_end = 12
day_end = 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead of using MONTH and DAY. And please confirm that dates in db are in **date** format

Comment: yes dates are in DATE format, can you explain me how to use DATE_FORMAT please?

Comment: try this
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_start,'%c') >= '".$month_start."' and DATE_FORMAT(date_start,'%d') >= '".$day_start."'" AND DATE_FORMAT(date_end,'%c') <= '".$month_end."' and DATE_FORMAT(date_end,'%d') <= '".$day_end."'"

Comment: tried this:

WHERE (DATE_FORMAT('01-09-0000','%c') >= '09' and DATE_FORMAT('01-09-0000','%d') >= '01') AND (DATE_FORMAT('31-12-0000','%c') <= '12' and DATE_FORMAT('31-12-0000','%d') <= '31') 

nothing changed :(

Comment: in where clause,it should be like DATE_FORMAT(date_start,'%c'), not DATE_FORMAT('01-09-0000','%c')

Comment: yes i tried also changing the format of the date from '01-09-0000' to '0000-09-01' .. still nothing

Answer (score 3):

why not use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE your_date BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
```

Comment: i can't find a solution using between, because when i make the query getting values fom a datepicker calendar i use 2 dates: date_start and date_end, not just 1 specific date. help please

Comment: try `(your_date1 BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) OR (your_date2 BETWEEN date_start AND date_end)`

Comment: can you add sample data/records?

Comment: tried this:
WHERE ('01-09-2012' BETWEEN date_start and date_end) OR ('31-10-2012' BETWEEN date_start and date_end)

doesn't work :(

Comment: you need to use `yyyy-MM-dd` format, by the way, what is the data type of *date_start* and *date_end*? try this again `WHERE ('2012-09-01' BETWEEN date_start and date_end) OR ('2012-10-31' BETWEEN date_start and date_end)`

Comment: i don't got year as good value, it is like 0000 ever, i got only months and days usable. date format is like 0000-01-31